# How to obtain mac address of a permanent interface in Qt

Tags: qt, network-programming, mac-address

My Qt application needs to uniquely identify computers it runs on. To achieve that, my current code probes its mac address using `QNetworkInterface` class like this:

```
QNetworkInterface intf;

#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
intf = QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromName(QString("en0"));
#endif

#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
intf = QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromIndex(0);
#endif

if(intf.isValid())
    QString mac_address = intf.hardwareAddress();
```

It seems to work on the few machines I have tested it on. But is the above strategy guaranteed to work on all machines? For example, can one rename the interface name to something different from "en0" on a Mac? If so, is there a better way to probe the mac address for the interface that will not change over time?

Comment: Why don't you always use `QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromIndex(0)` ?

Comment: Because on my Mac, the first index was blank. en0 happens to be the 4th address

Comment: I've learn something then :)

Comment: Do you compare the `mac_address` with a given value ?

Comment: Not quite. If the string is not blank, I use it in downstream logic. How would that matter though?

Comment: Well if the user changed the interface name (he can, but will he ?) you can browse all the interfaces and compare the address with the base of authorized ones

Comment: I used this approach before to create a hardware profile for a given machine but it is very error prone. Have you thought of VPN adapters, disabable devices, virtual machines? Just as an advice: Use other properties to identify a machine (downside: you certainly have to use native calls for every OS). For your question: It is possible to do that.

Comment: @Dominik, yes I agree this approach is not turning out to be error free. However, I don't need this to be extremely rock solid either. Can you share some examples of other properties you have in mind?

Comment: Well ... it depends on what you want. If you want to identify the machine for copy protection you should have a model that is not too restrictive (the user should be able to change hardware - at least e.g. 30% of the stuff that is used in your metric). Things you could use is a combination of: Install-HDD serial, CPU settings (id, cores, Mhz), RAM, Bios Vendor, BaseBoardProduct, machine GUID (on Windows), ... and MAC of your primary network interface ;-) )

Comment: Using the MAC of en0 is ok for a lot of purposes. I personally used the same approach some years ago and had problems since in e.g. enterprise environment a lot of people use virtual adapters that are hard to identify (e.g. on Windows) and sometimes have to temp. deactivate their network devices.

Comment: Well, my requirement is very similar to say Dropbox - the webserver needs to map user id to their machines. This is to avoid expensive folder index recalculations when a user logs off and then back again. Your suggestions of using install HDD serial looks promising. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: To the gentleman who edited my question, A) changing its to it's is grammatically incorrect when used as a possessive pronoun and B) is hardly significant to the issue being discussed here.